# Creating custom overlays for Google Maps

Tags: google-maps

I have a set of addresses, lets say restaurants, which I would like to plot on Google Maps and then make it possible for the user to rate them. I would also like to provide a search feature where the user can filter the restaurants by e.g. rating, food choice etc.

I have created the database architecture to store the restaurants and ratings, but how should I go around creating the overlay?

Are there already a feature where I can pinpoint an address and then supply my own html-code/iframe or alike, or do I need to create the overlay from the bottom myself?

I have looked at the [overlay API](http://code.google.com/intl/da/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays.html#SubClassing), but I can't seem to figure out what is the best way to go around doing it?

Answer (score 0):

I found out that the InfoBox would work.